# Cursor doesn't respect theme when program is launched from command line

Tags: customization, cursor, icon-themes, update-alternatives, cursor-theme

I installed `breeze-cursor-theme` with `apt`, and changed the default cursor theme via `update-alternatives`. Hence, `update-alternatives --get-selections | grep x-cursor-theme` returns

`x-cursor-theme                 auto     /etc/X11/cursors/breeze_cursors.theme`

However, when I launch some programs from the command line, e.g. `sxiv`, the cursor reverts to the default black cursor. When these programs are launched via `dmenu` or when run with `sudo`, the cursor theme is correct.

This is not the case for all programs; as examples, `zathura` and `gpick` do not share the problem, while `picard` and `calibre` do.

I have tried some other ways of setting the cursor theme:

- Using `lxappearance`
- Writing `Xcursor.theme: breeze_cursors` in `~/.Xresouces`.

Neither has made a difference. I also removed all other cursor themes from `/usr/share/icons/` and `~/icons/`.

I also tried copying the Breeze cursors into `~/icons/`, suspecting the file permissions
were the issue, to no avail.

I still suspect that it might be a permissions problem, since it works when run from a `TTY` or `?` (according to `ps aux`) and not when run from `pts/1`, `pts/2`, etc. To be specific, the first instance of `sxiv` (`PID=94893`) has the wrong cursors, while the other (`PID=94939`), called from `dmenu`, has the correct ones. Here is the output of `ps aux | head -1 && ps aux | grep sxiv | head -n -1`:

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
username   94893  0.0  0.1  28176 21116 pts/7    S+   22:34   0:00 sxiv /home/username/a.jpg
username   94939  0.0  0.1  28172 21044 ?        S    22:34   0:00 sxiv /home/username/b.jpg
```

I have this problem in both Wayland and X11 in KDE, Kubuntu, and my dwm setup in Debian. It persists, whether in `tmux` or not.

Comment: First of all, it is up to the developer to honor the theme settings. Second it depends on the library the program uses (GTK, QT, wxwidget, etc). Each library has its own theme config.

Comment: @Marco My question is not about setting the cursor theme; I have done that successfully and every application uses the correct cursor. The question is about why the cursor theme depends on who starts an application/where it is started. Even when started from the command line, applications are still respecting the themes that I have set up - just not the cursor theme.

Comment: The theme is configured in the users profile. Other users have other (cursor-)theme. Depending on the setting of your terminal, the shell inside gets the environment from the  starting process or reads it completely from scratch. Environment variable might influence the profile/theme.